# Is there a way of having a popup appear over a different applications?

Tags: android

I'm currently making an app when you touch the notification it opens a dialog activity that allows you to write a note. Only problem is that whenever it opens, the current app disappears. So is there any way for my popup to just be overlayed over the previous app?  Similar to the way the stock messaging app handles the quick response option

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the "Dialog" themes for your activity. One of Theme.Dialog, Theme.Holo.Dialog, or Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar is probably what you're looking for. You can define this on the relevant  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
   ...
</activity>
```

Obviously, you'll only want to use the Holo variant if you're targeting API level 11+ or using a library like ActionBarSherlock or HoloEverywhere to provide backward compatibility with older Android versions.

All of Android's default themes are defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml).